Android ONN app unresponsive after waking from long sleep
As the title says, our app is unresponsive when waking from a long sleep. Button presses on the Android ONN-provided remote have no effect. There is no prompt/dialogue option, the app just does not respond to button presses.
If the sleep is short (up to a few hours), then the app will respond to the remote control buttons. If the sleep is sufficiently long enough, then it will not respond.
Here's some info on our app. The UI is a React web app. The Android app loads the React app and provides data to it. Internet is required for the app to work.
Logs appear when the user presses a button and it works fine up until it becomes unresponsive. At which point, button presses will not create any logs.
Is there a way to restart the app after waking from a long sleep?
Thanks in advance!

You should probably expand on your question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What does "unresponsive" mean? Do you get an ANR? What are "the remote control buttons"? "React App" means ... React Native or like a web app that uses React? What have you done to solve this so far? What do the logs show you?

Thanks for the response. I updated my post. I haven't found any potential solutions to the problem just yet. I've only been doing research. In your opinion, does this seem more like an issue on the Android side of things as opposed to the React/UI side of things?

I don't know anything about running a React web app through android to comment on where the issue may lie, sorry. BTW, maybe it's obvious to React developers, but I still have no clue what "remote control buttons" are.

I am very much sure that there is a potential memory leak or resource exhaustion issue. Consider to optimize the app by Minimizing Memory Footprint & Component Performance (components that are slow to render). If you're using a development kit or specific libraries provided by ONN, consider reaching out to their support team for guidance on handling long sleep behavior or known issues with their tools.

@BobSmith Thanks for your input. Is there a reason why you think it is a memory leak?

Long-running code,
Poorly written functions,
Hardware limitations,
ANR (Application Not Responding) these are few reasons for app to become unresponsive. And without debugging it's difficult for anyone to guess exact reason.
